# When is the DOM created?

Tags: dom

I was wondering when the DOM is created ? Is it when the browser receives the response it first creates a DOM representation of HTML ? Also, where can I read about internal implementation of DOM for some popular browsers ?

Comment: Yes, also - WebKit, Blink and Mozilla are open source - there.

Comment: Thanks, found it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_DOM_Hacking_Guide